# How to render queryset according to radio buttons in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button, django-queryset

I need to render products list view according what user select in radio buttons in template
if user select "men" only products with gender='men' appear and so for women products , so how to do that correctly?
for that I coded some snippets but it didn't work ever
I need help to do that correctly
here is my code
models.py

```py
GENDER_CHOISES=(

        ('men', "Men"),
        ('women', "Women"),)
class Product(models.Model):
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug          = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description   = models.TextField()
    price         = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image         = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', null=True, blank=False)
    featured      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active        = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gender        = models.CharField(max_length=120,default="" ,choices=GENDER_CHOISES)
    timestamp     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```py
def ProductListView(request):
    if request.method=='post':

        queryset = Product.objects.filter(gender=request.POST.get(['gender']))
    else:
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/list.html"
    return render(request,template_name,{'object_list':queryset})
```

list.html

```py
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form  method='post'>
    <div class="mx-auto mx-0"></div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"  autocomplete="off" value='men'> Men
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="gender"   autocomplete="off" value='women'> Women
  </label>
</div></form>
{{object_list.count}}

        <div class="row">

    {% for product in object_list %}
    <div class="col">
        <!-- {{ forloop.counter }} -->
        {% include 'products/snippets/card.html'%}

        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
         </div></div>
         <div class="row"><div class="col-12"><hr></div>
       {%  else %}
           </div>
       {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Any help Appreciated  & Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you submitting this form?

Comment: there is no submit its just buttons when user click on Men i need to show him  just products for men

Comment: then how are you sending your values to your backend? ajax?

Comment: I was expecting  queryset = Product.objects.filter(gender=request.POST.get(['gender'])) is enough 
 @NalinDobhal

Comment: you need to send the values from the front end. then only back-end will process the request. You can include a submit button in your html or you can use ajax to send values to your back-end.

Comment: I didn't ever use ajax , is submit button is  enougth eve it was hidden?

Comment: submit button should be visible, so that it can be clicked. If you dont want to show a submit button, then you have to use ajax.

Comment: Thanks this is most helpful, thanks so much